# Maximum of column and zero

Tags: ms-access

I would like to know how to get computed field in MS Access that shows maximum of a number or zero. I mean the function that is similar to the one in Excel `Max(A1,0)`. How do I get this in Access expression builder?

Comment: Try: `MAX([field_name],0)`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the only problem you could face, is that if the field has a null value. To be safe, wrap the field with the [Nz()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) function which replaces null to the given argument.

```
Max(Nz([YourFieldName],0))
```

When the field is numeric, the zero can be omitted.

```
Max(Nz([YourFieldName]))
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT IIf(YourField > 0, YourField, 0)
FROM YourTable;

This is what I had done, but i thought there was another way

Thank you very much for your quick responses

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).